# How set query filters for mongo in apache camel?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, apache-camel

I have this routes

```
from("timer:aTimer?fixedRate=true&period="+ ReaderXmlVenta.MILISEC_VENTA)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .to("http4://"+ReaderXmlVenta.URL_VENTA)
            .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
            .process("camelProcessor")
       .to("mongodb:mongoBeandatabase=eicas&collection=sales&operation=update)

            .to("log:org.apache.camel.example?level=DEBUG")
            .to("log:Ok:Se guardo un registro Venta fija");
```

But, I need filters into the query for update determinate registry

How I do this ? 
Do I have to add the filter in query in the route or in my "camelProcessor"?

Comment: Do you mean the filters described on the [Camel-MongoDB page](http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html)? They are described for the different operations.

Comment: Yeah! But it's the out of context the code and not works!

Comment: This is the code of Apache Camel-MongoDB

`DBObject filterField = new BasicDBObject("filterField", true);
DBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("scientist", "Darwin"));
Object result = template.requestBodyAndHeader("direct:update", new Object[] {filterField, updateObj}, MongoDbConstants.MULTIUPDATE, true);`

But I don't know whats its de variable "template". Because isn't static variable

Comment: Well this code is using a `producerTemplate` to send a message to a `direct:` Camel route that just does the `.to("mongodb:...)` part. This route is in the comment above the code. Anyway, it seems you need to have an `Object[]` as message body with your update object and the filter.

Comment: I try with this

`DBObject filterField = new BasicDBObject (" level1 "," VentaFija "); exchange.getOut (). setBody (nuevo DBObject [] {filterField, dbObject.get (0)});`

and don't save. The log is : 

`failed : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: Object[], Body: [Ljava.lang.Object;@35b73129]`

Comment: Try to set the body of the **in** message (not out): `exchange.getIn().setBody()`. See [this FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html) for the reasons.